# Angular X-editable timepicker or external jQuery plugin

Tags: jquery, angularjs, timepicker, x-editable

I am using angular x-editable (Editable row) in Laravel. I would like to add timepicker with some extra configuration (there is no in x-editable time). What is more I need to read and write data to database.

I was trying to use x-editable time and timepicker jQuery plugin, but I still don't know how to integrate timepicker with field which is generated by x-editable (table row).
The most satisfied result for me will be add external timepicker jQuery plugin.

Is there any possibility to add external jQuery plugin into field in x-editable table if not is there any way to integrate field generated by x-editable (Editable row) to add time to database and add some extra configuration to it?

Any help or advice is welcome.

Answer (score 1):

What about the HTML5 date/time picker?

```
<input type="time" name="usr_time">
```

ui-bootstrap is another good option for something more nice looking:
https://github.com/Gillardo/bootstrap-ui-datetime-picker